# HTTPs vs HTTP Connectivity Issues (Wifi)

Tags: internet, wireless-router

A friend of mine is facing a weird issue. He recently setup a Wireless router and is now unable to access HTTP sites. He is able to access sites over HTTPs.

What can be done to rectify this issue?

Comment: What happens when he tries to access them?

Answer (score 3):

Check the router's firewall settings... Sounds like port 80 is being blocked.

Comment: Thanks. This is NetGear's plug-and-play router with minimal config. Same prob when accessing through a tablet (WiFi). So can u share a few more pointers regarding the settings? (my friend says no antiviruses or other firewall settings prevent internet access)

Comment: Provide the model number of the router and we can check the documentation on-line.  The tablet rules out configuration on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the router has a setting that is blocking HTTP traffic. You say it's plug and play - this probably isn't the default. If it's easy to do try doing a factory reset. NetGear has many wireless routers, what model is it exactly? Without this information it's not possible to help more.